# Is there an Electron / Blazor Hot Reload?

Tags: visual-studio, electron, blazor

I'm currently using Blazor with Electron in Visual Studio 2022. Blazor with Visual Studio 2022 has a hot reload option that works, but I cannot get it to work with Electron. I have tried installing electron-reload. I even have in my launchSettings.json file the following

```
  "profiles": {
"Electron.NET App": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "electronize",
  "commandLineArgs": "start",
  "workingDirectory": ".",
  "watch":  true
},
```

with the watch option set to true. This is not working. I tried to add /watch to the commandLineArgs and the application will no longer run when I do that.